# keep getting UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to an AWS instance that I just set up for the first time using my Macbook. I have tried everything that I could find (AWS support page, google, Youtube, ChatGPT). I'm stuck and feel very opposite of smart or competent.

I have tried:

```
chmod 400
chmod 0400 
chmod 600
ssh -v -i
```

(which just basically verified I was connecting and then being denied)

Comment: Please show the full commands you used and the actual debug output. Also, please tell us why you think the connection should be permitted -- for example, did you select that keypair when launching the Amazon EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change permissions on the key file. For example, if the file is called `my-key.pem`:

```
chmod 600 my-key.pem

ssh -i my-key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4
```